# jQuery Conflicting with MooTools: Uncaught TypeError: self.className.contains is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I've got an app that uses both jQuery and MooTools.  In the past, I've been able to get around the conflict with `jQuery.noConflict()`, but there appears to be a particular page where `jQuery.noConflict()` works in an unexpected way: in particular, the `getElementByClass` polyfill is being overridden by MooTools.

The following will fail, with the following error:

`var $j = jQuery.noConflict(),
var $myElements = $j(".my-element");`

Returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: self.className.contains is not a
>   functionSelectors.Filters.byClass @
>   mootools-1.2.js:2766Selectors.Utils.filter @
>   mootools-1.2.js:2635Selectors.Utils.search @
>   mootools-1.2.js:2700Native.implement.getElements @
>   mootools-1.2.js:2532Native.implement.getElementsByClassName @
>   mootools-1.2.js:9638c.querySelectorAll.k @
>   jquery.1.6.4.min.js:3f.fn.extend.find @
>   jquery.1.6.4.min.js:3e.fn.e.init @ jquery.1.6.4.min.js:2e @
>   jquery.1.6.4.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ VM16934:6

I've tried to get jQuery "re-initialized" to its default by bringing in the script via CDN, but that also fails.

How can I reset jQuery to have its former methods?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use mootools 1.2, it pre-dates the native methods ES5 has for `String.prototype.contains` and `Array.prototype.contains` and is about 5-6 yrs old.

Either way, MooTools won't overwrite `Element.prototype.getElementByClassName`, which won't be used in a modern browser selector anyway - so unless you support IE6, this makes little sense, sizzle and slick will both use `querySelectorAll`

Furthermore. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789036

MooTools' `String.prototype.contains` broke browsers and forced a bunch of fixes to be rolled out, inlcluding 1.2.6 and 1.3

And lastly.

`self.className.contains` is not helpful - is this your own code or is it in MooTools - normally, self is a hack to keep scope to an instance, unusual for it to point to an `Element`, which will have a `className` property. what happens when you `console.log(self.className)`?